# values being updated in wrong columns in mySql table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

The following is my code in a jsp page : AdminModifyGrocery3.jsp:

```
int g_id = session.getAttribute("g_id") != null ? ((Integer) session.getAttribute("g_id")).intValue() : 0 ;
String g_name=(String)request.getParameter("g_name");
String g_price_string=(String)request.getParameter("g_price");  
int g_price = Integer.parseInt(g_price_string);

PreparedStatement stmtUpdate = null;
String strUpdate = "update ShopSystem.Grocery set g_name= ? where g_id = ?";
stmtUpdate = con.prepareStatement(strUpdate);
stmtUpdate.setString(1,g_name);
stmtUpdate.setInt(2,g_id);
int c2 = stmtUpdate.executeUpdate();

PreparedStatement stmtUpdate1 = null;
String strUpdate1 = "update ShopSystem.Grocery set g_price=? where g_id=?";
stmtUpdate1 = con.prepareStatement(strUpdate);
stmtUpdate1.setInt(1,g_price);
stmtUpdate1.setInt(2,g_id);
int c1 = stmtUpdate1.executeUpdate();

if(c2>0 && c1>0)
{
    %> 
    <br> Data is modified successfully.<br>
    <% 
}
else
{
    %> 
    <br> Sorry the action cannot be completed.<br> 
    <%  
}
```

It is displaying the message "Data is modified successfully."
But in the actual database it is setting the g_price value to g_name, and it is retaining the g_price original value as it is instead of modifying it!
What could be going wrong!

Comment: You should post your database schema.

Comment: Do you really think it is efficient to use two update statements instead of one?

Comment: You have to show uos the schema definition (CREATE TABLE statements).

Comment: Table name : Grocery; columns : g_id : Int(11); g_name : varchar(45); g_price : int(11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have an error using variable:

```
String strUpdate1 = "update ShopSystem.Grocery set g_price=? where g_id=?";
stmtUpdate1 = con.prepareStatement(strUpdate);
                                       ^^^^^^
stmtUpdate1.setInt(1,g_price);
stmtUpdate1.setInt(2,g_id);
```

You have to use `strUpdate1` at the marked position.

or you can use on statement:

```
String strUpdate = "update ShopSystem.Grocery set g_name= ?, g_price=?   where g_id = ?";
stmtUpdate = con.prepareStatement(strUpdate);
stmtUpdate.setString(1,g_name);
stmtUpdate.setString(2,g_price);
stmtUpdate.setInt(3,g_id);
int c2 = stmtUpdate.executeUpdate();
```

And remove the second statement.